# Still confused about Pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using an old exam as a study guide and one of the questions is to use pthreads to fill in the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    } local_data;

void *foo(void *arg);

int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int b = 9;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    local_data local;
    local.a = a;
    local.b = b;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    /* block of code we are supposed to fill in (my attempt at filling it in)
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, foo, &local);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    */

    b = b - 5;
    printf("program exit. a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}

void *foo(void *arg) {
     int a, b;
     local_data *local = (local_data*)arg;

    /* block of code we are supposed to fill in (my attempt at filling it in)
    a = local->a;
    b = local->b;
    a++;
    */

    printf("program exit. a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

What we are supposed to do is make our pthreads mimic this code:

```
int main() {
    int a = 12;
    int b = 9;
    int fid = fork();

    if (fid == 0) {
        a++;
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);
        b = b - 5;
    }

    printf("program exit. a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I've been really lost on this section and I am sure I do not understand it as well as I should (or at all). Would appreciate any answers to help me grasp the concept.

Comment: `local_data *local` is a pointer declaration, so `local.a` should be `local->a` instead.

Comment: @K-ballo Thanks for catching that!

Comment: You've edited the original post to include @Brendan's answer. Are you still having issues? If so, you should add more information to help us figure out what's wrong. If not, you should accept Brendan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, foo(local), NULL);
```

[`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html)'s signature is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
    void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);
```

The third argument is a function and the last argument is it's argument, so instead of calling the function (`foo(local)`), pass the function and the argument separately:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, foo, &local);
```

Comment: @Brendan Thanks! I didn't quite understand the syntax. This clears it up a bit.

Comment: @jswolf19 Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @jswolf19 - This is the part that stood out to me. If there's more, I'd suggest making your own answer (so you can get the credit).

Comment: @Brendan, no, this is the major part. I imagine that `b` being uninitialized is pretty easy to find once you get to the point of passing the correct arguments to `pthread_create`.